# Example of weak limit not in the set

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, weak-convergence, hahn-banach-theorem

Let $(E, \| \cdot \| _E)$ be a normed vector space over a field $\mathbb{K}$ and $E'$ be its dual space.

**Theorem:** Let $C\subset E$ be a closed (respect to the strong topology $\| \cdot \| _E$) and convex set. If a sequence $\{x_n\}\rvert_{n\in \mathbb{n\in N}}\subset C$ converges weakly to a $x\in E$, then $x\in C$.

**Question:** What happens if $C$ is a *non convex set* ? Equivalent: Find a counterexample where $C\subset E$ is a closed set (respect the strong topology $\| \cdot \| _E$) but a **non convex** set and
$$x_n \rightharpoonup x \notin C.$$
Is this even possible?

Note: *The notation $x_n \rightharpoonup x$ means $x_n$ converges weakly to $x$.*

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\{e_n\}$ be an orthonrmal set in Hilbert space. Then $e_n \to 0$ weakly and $\{e_1,e_2,\cdots\}$ is a closed set in the norm. The limit $0$ is not in this set.

Comment: Dear sir. Thanks for your answer. Simple but quite correct!